# Check if ID in array Value

Tags: arrays, magento, collections, filter

I have a custom table & collection in magento where one of the values for each item will always equal if not null (which can be changed on saveAction in the controller);

```
3,5,7...saved store ids
```

In the frontend I have a block that will be the collection that is filtered like so;

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('things/things')->getCollection();

    //Stored Array, checks if value is in the array (which is jsut the current store view)
    //store = 3,5,7 
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('store', array('in' => array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
```

Does magento automatically know that the stored `store` value can be an array and checks that the value equals the filter? example below;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have use `finset` add store filter

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('store', array('finset' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()));
```

Comment: very clever! thanks dude, what about if the 'store' item value is 0?

Comment: check if this `$collection` give you `0` result then add filter with `0` mean all store view

Comment: Would I do that in the template.phtml file as the above $collection is done in Block/Things.php. Each item in the collection can have either 0 or 3,4,5...as the value but if equals 0 the item is not output even though its enabled for all store views (=0)..

Comment: first check is always for current store if condition false then it will go for all store view. the first occurrence you will use..

Comment: Ok but if the "all store views" is selected (which stores as 0) the item is not output in the foreach within the phtml file

Comment: Ok got it I used a notnull condition as well: $collection->addFieldToFilter('stores', array("notnull"=>false, 'finset' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()));